# Get YouTube link from content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have content with a string and some images and some video, and I need to get only the video in this content. How can I do that?

I tried it the following way, but sometimes I do not get video and sometimes it gets me a video link:

```
<?php

    $string = $post->post_content;

    $pattern = '/(http\S*(?=(?:&|\?)rel))/im';

    $array = array();

    preg_match($pattern, $string, $array);

    $link = $array[0];

    print '<video>'.$link.'</video>';

?>
```

The example of my content is like:

```
    Quinquaginta septem est – pars tua, triginta quinque millia. Est autem extra plus quindecim, tota tua est, quom meruisset. Fac nos fecit. SIC. Puto quia una res potest – venimus in cognitionem. Vide pretium in…

    https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&v=1MBWZWyvMng

    Respice … Sentio sicut ego vobis exponam: sed vias breve iterum conabor. Fugere hoc maior difficultas est nobis. Perdet eam batch nostri. Et delebis eam ac omnia opus est vestigium, ut possimus coques. Sin id, quod morte morieris. Locus non est peccatum. Nec apud hos.

 [youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&v=1MBWZWyvMng]
```

Comment: Are you able to show the the input string ($string) in it's various formats?

Comment: what you mean ? are you mean i can get the content ? yes i get all content but i need only video type

Comment: he means that you should give us examples for your content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple

```
preg_match_all('/https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/[^\s]*v\=|youtu\.be\/)([a-z0-9]+)/is', $input, $matches);
```

will output all youtube-links in your string. 
$input is the datasource
$matches will return the matches in an array.

Comment: its return me all link in the content, i need only youtube

Comment: nice, but i get in the end of link `https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBWZWyvMng]` its must like `https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBWZWyvMng` why add `]` in the end of link

Comment: its still return me `]` and some video return `?`

Comment: Have you looked in all data of the array?

Comment: yes its get youtube link but add in the end `]` why !!

Comment: Nice now work good, but if i have more than video, How can show it ... now show me only first video

Comment: Post the output of $matches pls

Comment: here is my code `$string = $post->post_content;

$pattern = '/https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be|youtube\.com)\/[^\s]*v\=([a-z0-9]+)/is';

$array = array();

preg_match($pattern, $string, $array);

$link = $array[0];
if ($link){
 print '<video>'.$link.'</video>';
}`

Comment: and return me `Array
(
    [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBWZWyvMng
)`

Comment: You need to use preg_match_all() function, not preg_match. And use the regex i posted now.

Comment: nice i use it ,, the result is `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBWZWyvMng
            [1] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBdrWyvdet
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)` how can output it like
`<video>https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBWZWyvMng</video>
<video>https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=110&amp;v=1MBdrWyvdet</video>`

Comment: Well i tested it myself now. I posted the final regex and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
youtube[^\] ]+
```

Test this simple pattern